# Irregular Run-Time Errors in VBA using Copy Paste of a Shape

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, runtime-error, shapes

I'm curious about 2 VBA runtime errors. The curious thing is: 9 out of 10 times the code works perfectly fine. But from time to time one of the 2 following runtime errors appears:

`Run-Time error '1004': Paste method of Picture object failed`

`Run-time error -214724809 (80070057): The index into the specified collection is out of bounds.`

I could not identify any dependencies when it will or will not appear.

This is what I do:

1. Click on a button in Excel wich will perform the following steps via VBA
2. Create a new sheet 'Detailinterview'
3. Copy a logo from sheet 'data'
4. Paste it to sheet 'Detailinterview'

This is my code

```
Public Const DATA = "Data"
Public Const DETAILINTERVIEW = "Detailinterview"

Public Sub DoMagic()
  Dim logo As Shape

  'Some other code

  For Each logo In Sheets(DATA).Shapes
    If logo.Name = "MY_LOGO" Then
        logo.Copy
        Sheets(DETAILINTERVIEW).Pictures.Paste ' runtime error 1004
    End If
  Next

  ' Hint: Sheet DETAILINTERVIEW contains only 1 shape: MY_LOGO
  Set logo = Worksheets(DETAILINTERVIEW).Shapes(1) 'runtime error -214724809 
  If Not logo Is Nothing Then
    logo.IncrementLeft 580
    logo.IncrementTop 4
  End If
End Sub
```

Why is VBA crashing? Why is it only crashing from time to time? How can I fix it?

Thanks in advance!

---

As requested here is the rest of the code:

```
Public Const DATA = "Data"
Public Const DETAILINTERVIEW = "Detailinterview"

Public Sub DoMagic()
    Dim logo As Shape
    Dim i As Long
    Dim sheetExists As Boolean

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    For i = 1 To Sheets.Count
        If Sheets(i).Name = DETAILINTERVIEW Then
          sheetExists = True
          Debug.Print MsgBox("A worksheet 'Detailinterview' exists already!", vbOKOnly)  
          Exit Sub
        End If
    Next i

    Worksheets("Datenblatt_Template").Copy after:=Worksheets(QUESTION_SELECTION)
    Worksheets("Datenblatt_Template (2)").Visible = True
    Worksheets("Datenblatt_Template (2)").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Name = DETAILINTERVIEW
    Worksheets(DETAILINTERVIEW).Columns("I:I").ColumnWidth = 1
    Worksheets(DETAILINTERVIEW).Columns("K:K").ColumnWidth = 33
    Worksheets(DETAILINTERVIEW).Columns("M:M").ColumnWidth = 17
    Worksheets(DETAILINTERVIEW).Columns("O:O").ColumnWidth = 3

    ActiveWindow.DisplayGridlines = False
    ActiveWindow.DisplayHeadings = False
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(DETAILINTERVIEW).Range("A:H").EntireColumn.Hidden = True

    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Templates").Range("T_HEADER").Copy
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(DETAILINTERVIEW).Activate
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(DETAILINTERVIEW).Rows("1:1").Select
    ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Paste

    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Templates").Range("T_MASTER_HEADER").Copy
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(DETAILINTERVIEW).Activate
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(DETAILINTERVIEW).Rows("2:2").Select
    ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Paste

    Worksheets(DETAILINTERVIEW).Range("J2").Value = Range(START & "!C20") & " - " & Range(START & "!C21") & " - " & Range(START & "!C22")

    For Each logo In Sheets(DATA).Shapes
        If logo.Name = "MY_LOGO" Then
             logo.Copy
             Sheets(DETAILINTERVIEW).Pictures.Paste ' runtime error 1004
        End If
    Next

    ' Hint: Sheet DETAILINTERVIEW contains only 1 shape: MY_LOGO
    Set logo = Worksheets(DETAILINTERVIEW).Shapes(1) 'runtime error -214724809 
    If Not logo Is Nothing Then
        logo.IncrementLeft 580
        logo.IncrementTop 4
    End If

    ' Some more Magic
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you sure `detailinreview` exists? And that the index of the shape you want is actually 1? I'm pretty sure your second error is because whatever you want doesn't exist, but then you check to see if it exists?

Comment: The sheet definitely exists. It is created in `some other code`. And I also used `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(DETAILINTERVIEW).Shapes("MY_LOGO")` before, instead of `Shapes(1)`. But it resulted in the same strange runtime error.

Comment: Please post the rest of your code.

Answer (score -1):

Using `Select`, `Activate` etc. is dangerous. You should instead explicitly qualify your objects with their parents. Ex.

```
Sheets(1).Range("A1").value = 1
```

Is better than

```
Sheets(1).Activate
Range("A1").Select
Selection.Value = 1
```

I cleaned up your code a bit:

```
Option Explicit

Public Const DATA = "Data"
Public Const DETAILINTERVIEW = "Detailinterview"

Public Sub DoMagic()
    Dim logo As Shape
    Dim i As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    For i = 1 To Sheets.Count
        If Sheets(i).Name = DETAILINTERVIEW Then
          Debug.Print MsgBox("A worksheet " & DETAILINTERVIEW & " exists already!", vbOKOnly)
          Exit Sub
        End If
    Next i

Dim ws As Worksheet
With ThisWorkbook
    .Worksheets("Datenblatt_Template").Copy after:=.Worksheets(.Worksheets.Count)
    Set ws = .Worksheets(.Worksheets.Count)
End With
With ws
    .Name = DETAILINTERVIEW
    .Columns("I:I").ColumnWidth = 1
    .Columns("K:K").ColumnWidth = 33
    .Columns("M:M").ColumnWidth = 17
    .Columns("O:O").ColumnWidth = 3

    ActiveWindow.DisplayGridlines = False
    ActiveWindow.DisplayHeadings = False
    .Range("A:H").EntireColumn.Hidden = True

    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Templates").Range("T_HEADER").Copy Destination:=.Range("A1")
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Templates").Range("T_MASTER_HEADER").Copy Destination:=.Range("A2")

    '***************************
    'I can't get the next line to run because Start is uninitialized 
    '.Range("J2").Value = Range(Start & "!C20") & " - " & Range(Start & "!C21") & " - " & Range(Start & "!C22")
    '****************************

    For Each logo In Sheets(DATA).Shapes
        If logo.Name = "MY_LOGO" Then
             logo.Copy
             .Pictures.Paste
             .Shapes(1).IncrementLeft 580
             .Shapes(1).IncrementTop 4
             Exit For
        End If
    Next
    If .Shapes.Count < 1 Then Debug.Print "Logo not found"
End With
    ' Some more Magic
End Sub
```